# WordPress/Gravity Forms Popup Maker Issue

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I’m currently working on integrating a gravity form on a landing page of the DAW site using the Popup Maker plugin. I was able to get most of it completed but it seems like the CSS doesn’t want to resize for mobile. When you visit the page (https://dawstaging.wpengine.com/branding-2/)and click on the “Let’s do it” button on the initial popup, larger popup appears and on mobile this popup is quite large.

Adjusting the width for mobile seems fine but adjusting the height is giving me issues. I want to know if you have any insight into how to resolve this?

I have tried targeting various CSS classes in media queries but it appears that the Gravity Forms has a limit to the height. There is a form at the bottom of the page that resizes just fine. I'm sure I'm missing something here.